# DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, linux

Bit of background as this may be important to this error.

1. I have a VPS and I use the Plesk control panel, I recently upgraded my VPS, which caused my partition storage to be full, this was the first error I had, so I followed [this guide](https://docs.ovh.com/gb/en/vps/repartitioning-vps-after-upgrade/) to re-partition.
2. After re-partitioning, I was met with the following error: `DB query failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`

Result of systemctl status mysql.service:

```
    mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
    Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-05-25 11:14:29 CEST; 2s ago
    Process: 22367 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
    May 25 11:16:35 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon...
    May 25 11:16:35 mysql[22939]: /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too     ful...iled!
    May 25 11:16:35 /etc/init.d/mysql[22957]: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!
    May 25 11:16:35 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    May 25 11:16:35 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
    May 25 11:16:35 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

It's curious that it's still showing the partition is still full, I thought I'd deleted it and created a new one, so I am thinking something went wrong during the partition process.

Result of df -h:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        25G   25G     0 100% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           393M   40M  353M  11% /run
tmpfs           982M     0  982M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           982M     0  982M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           197M     0  197M   0% /run/user/0
```

result of du -sh /var/lib/mysql:

```
521M    /var/lib/mysql
```

Really stuck and do not know how to go about fixing this, I would be eternally grateful for any help.